# What is the best free mobile development ide?

Tags: c++, iphone, ide

I want to try to design a mobile app that is cross compatible. I am a computer science major and I have experience in both C++, C#, and Basic. I also have experience in HTML, CSS, PHP, and Javascript. I have only ever made computer applications but I would like to start developing mobile applications. Where do I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode for IOS
Eclipse for Android
Visual Studio for Windows mobile.

You can use some other IDEs as well but for the IDEs i mentioned above you can find quite a lot of support. 
Its very good that you are planning to build app with C++ because if you code properly you can reuse most of the code to Android, IOS and for Windows mobile. but i prefer you to code in Java for android unless your extremely comfortable with C++. because since you said you know C# java is not much different comparing to C#.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged iPhone you don't have a lot of choice but xCode.

If you want Windows Phone apps, you can use Visual Studio.

Symbian (lol) - QtCreator.

Andorid - ANdroid development SDK and eclipse.

BlackBerry (10.x) - QNX Momentics IDE (modified eclipse)

EDIT:
As for cross-compatible, i must say that by using HTML5 as a base you can make the next best thing...